# Machine date time format overrides code date time format

Tags: c#, .net

Below code:

```
 Console.WriteLine($"-b \"{DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2):M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss}\"");
```

gives correct output for one machine (with no change in date/time format):

```
-b "6/19/2018 07:45:44"
```

but when I am running code on a different machine (where date/time format was changed), I'm not getting the expected output:

```
-b "6-19-2018 07:20:17"
```

What's wrong? do I need to add "Invariant Culture", etc?

Comment: so you run the same code but on different machines and get different results on formatting? I guess I'm trying to understand, is it the date and time that is wrong or the formatting that is wrong?

Comment: @AlexW Yes, of course and it is as to be expected. OP ask about 6/19/2018 vs. 6-19-2018

Comment: It is documented https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier-1

Comment: @AlexW, Yes, both machine different settings for Date/Time. Both machine different output. Question, can we get same output from both machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify a date & time format, it is executed using the current thread culture. If you don't specify the thread culture, it is by default taken from the computer's culture. So when you run the same code on two different computers that have two different cultures, you may get two different date & time format.

In the format that you have, the `/` is a date separator and the `:` is a time separator. They are both substituted by the date and time separators of the thread culture. In your scenario, it seems that the date separator on the second machine is `-` and this is what you get.

To use `/` and `:` regardless of the machine's culture, surround them with single quotes like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"-b \"{DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2):M'/'d'/'yyyy hh':'mm':'ss}\"");
```

Comment: Yes Correct, Question: can I can same output for both machine by change in code?

Comment: The more you know, I actually didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is printing `quotes` also...Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: What quotes? You mean the double quotes? Those were part of your code, you can remove them if you want.

Comment: Ok, got it. I can replace that